# Have Phonegap 1.4.1 and Cordova 2.0 installed side by side?

Tags: cordova

Hey Fellow Phonegap Fans. Does anyone have any idea if I can have Phonegap 1.4.1 (which I would say is the last great stable Phonegap) installed alongside of Cordova 2.0?

I have a few apps using 1.4.1 that I don't want to rock with newer versions yet, but would like to start dev with 2.0 at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes, yes you can install both at the same time.